# Ubuntu 12.10 get MAC like Icon Launcher

Tags: 12.10, themes, macosx, ios

Anyway to get an Mac OS X style docker like this in the simplest way?

[image]

I do not want a full redo of my Ubuntu theme, I just want the icon launcher look alike, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Cairo dock is a good option, check it out on http://glx-dock.org/

To install, just type `sudo apt-get install cairo-dock` on terminal

Answer (score 0):

Plank is another great option! It's currently what elementaryos uses.

Install guide: http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Plank:Installing